# How to concatenate pathname and relative pathname?

Tags: perl, concatenation

I have a task where I need to concatenate 2 pathnames: absolute + relative in perl. The following describes what I am trying to achieve:

```
dir1/dir2/dir3/ + ../filename => dir1/dir2/filename
dir1/dir2/dir3/ + ../../filename => dir1/filename
```

I have only solution that counts ".." in relative path, say X, then splits the absolute path into dirs and count them - Y and  finally concatenates only Y-X dirs with filename. This seems too bulky and I wonder whether better solution exists (I am sure it does). Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe [File::Spec::rel2abs](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html) in combination with [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) will help ?

Comment: Actually my task was to concatenate two URLs that is why I didn't notice that File::Spec is applicable in that case also. After your comment I looked at File::Spec and found solution the same time as bvr. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ perl -MURI -E'say URI->new($ARGV[1])->abs($ARGV[0]);' \
    http://foo.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/ ../filename
http://foo.com/dir1/dir2/filename

$ perl -MURI -E'say URI->new($ARGV[1])->abs($ARGV[0]);' \
    http://foo.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/ ../../filename
http://foo.com/dir1/filename
```

It even works with two relative URLS like the ones you have.

```
$ perl -MURI -E'say URI->new($ARGV[1])->abs($ARGV[0]);' \
    /dir1/dir2/dir3/ ../filename
/dir1/dir2/filename

$ perl -MURI -E'say URI->new($ARGV[1])->abs($ARGV[0]);' \
    /dir1/dir2/dir3/ ../../filename
/dir1/filename
```

Comment: `URI->new($ARGV[1])->abs($ARGV[0])` can also be written as `URI->new_abs($ARGV[1], $ARGV[0])`.

Answer (score 4):

You can look at [File::Spec](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aSpec), namely `catdir` method:

```
use File::Spec;

print File::Spec->catdir('dir1/dir2/dir3', '../filename'),"\n";
print File::Spec->catdir('dir1/dir2/dir3', '../../filename', ),"\n";
```

Comment: Thank you. However File::Spec->catdir() overdoes a bit in my case since it changes path separator in paths to system one but I need to preserve original. But this is not hard to add conversion.

Comment: @pmod - note that you can also `use` specific system implementation like [File::Spec::Unix](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Spec::Unix) to get desired separators. I don't know of any that would keep those used in parameters, though.

Comment: File::Spec(::Unix) does not produce the desired effect. It produces `dir1/dir2/dir3/../filename` because `dir1/dir2/filename` is not necessarily equivalent. (Think of symlinks.)

Comment: @ikegami - you are correct.  I did not notice because I run on Windows, where paths are collapsed. `File::Spec::Unix` indeed produces path with updirs.