# Perl directory concatenation

Tags: perl, path, absolute-path

Is there a function say `f` (in base Perl or a library) such that:

```
f("/a/b/c", "./d") == "/a/b/c/d"
f("/a/b/c", "../d") == "/a/b/d"
f("/a/b/c", "/d") == "/d"
```

Basically, it returns the directory that would result from repeatedly `cd`ing.

Comment: You can write your own!

Comment: Dunno if there's one built in, but it'd be easy to make one.  :P  `$pwd = $ENV{PWD}; chdir $path1; chdir $path2; $result = $ENV{PWD}; chdir $pwd;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579495/how-to-concatenate-pathname-and-relative-pathname](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579495/how-to-concatenate-pathname-and-relative-pathname)

Comment: @Umair Azmi, That post is for urls, not file paths.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Core's [File::Spec](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aSpec) has such a function (`rel2abs`), but I prefer [Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Path%3a%3aClass) (because it's too easy to use File::Spec incorrectly).

```
use Path::Class qw( dir );
say dir('./d')->absolute('/a/b/c');    # /a/b/c/d
say dir('../d')->absolute('/a/b/c');   # /a/b/d
say dir('/d')->absolute('/a/b/c');     # /d
```

Use `file` instead of `dir` if you're create a path to a file.

By the way, `./d` is just a wordy way of writing `d`.

---

Oops, on unix systems, that returns `/a/b/c/../d` for the middle one because it's impossible to know `/a/b/c/../d` means `/a/b/d` without checking the file system. (It could actually be `/a/b/e/f/d`.) Off the top of my head, I don't know any tool that makes absolute paths by checking the file system using a base other than the pwd.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is missing many things, but a function `f` can be like this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

sub f {
  my ($s, $cd) = @_; 
  return $cd if ($cd =~ m!^/!); # return path if abs
  $cd =~ s!//+!/!g;
  my @v = split(/\//, $cd);
  my @i = split(/\//, $s);
  for my $c (@v) {
    next if $c eq ".";
    pop @i, next if $c eq "..";
    push @i, $c; 
  }
  return join("/", @i);
}

my @p = ( 
  ["/a/b/c", "./d"], 
  ["a/b/c", "../d"], 
  ["/a/b/c/", "/d"], 
  ["a/b/c/e/f/g", "../../c/e/../d"]);

print f(@$_), "\n" for @p;
```